# MS Excel polynomial regression curve vs. Calculated polynomial regreesion curve results on different equations

Tags: regression, regression-analysis

I've been doing some research based on polynomial regression curves: $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$

I did all the research on MS Excel, and built some notes based on that.

Then, I created a C program that calculates the polynimial regression curves based on following equation system

$$a_0n + a_1\sum x_i + a_2\sum x_i^2 = \sum y_i$$
$$a_0\sum x_i + a_1\sum x_i^2 + a_2\sum x_i^3 = \sum x_i y_i$$
$$a_0\sum x_i^2 + a_1\sum x_i^3 + a_2\sum x_i^4 = \sum x_i^2 y_i$$

That is supossed to generate $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ equivalent equation once the equation system is solved.

But, after the first test, I realise that MS Excel generated equation and my equation were different

Equation given by MS Excel for particular data: $-100x^2 + 26600x - 122290 = 0$

Equation given by my EXE for particular data: $-1x^2 + 2242x - 1199041 = 0$

So, **there's obviously a difference on the calculation, I assume that it have to be on the given data**.

On MS Excel I have

```
   x     f(x)
   1     -
  11     -
  21     -
  31     -
 ...     -
1101     57200
1111     57500
1121     57600
 ...     ...
```

Data from $x = 1$ to $x = 991$ are on other data series, then from $x = 1101$ are on the data series I'm searching, so, on my EXE file I went directly to $x = 1101$, then got

```
   x     f(x)
1101     57200
1111     57500
1121     57600
```

To illustrate, MS Excel full graph (my EXE file goes thru the most inner parabola - dark blue colored):
[image: Graph]

Data table I was treating on MS Excel:

```
x       Serie1      Serie2      Serie3      Serie4      Serie5
1                   
11                  
21                  
31                  
41                  
51                  
61                  
71                  
81                  
91                  
101                 
111                 
121                 
131                 
141                 
151                 
161                 
171                 
181                 
191                 
201                 
211                 
221                 
231                 
241                 
251                 
261                 
271                 
281                 
291                 
301                 
311                 
321                 
331                 
341                 
351                 
361                 
371                 
381                 
391                 
401                 
411                 
421                 
431                 
441                 
451                 
461                 
471                 
481                 
491                 
501                 
511                 
521                 
531                 
541                 
551                 
561                 
571                 
581                 
591                                                     13100
601                                                     27600
611                                                     41900
621                                                     56000
631                                         6800    
641                                         19500   
651                                         32000   
661                                         44300   
671                                         56400   
681                             200     
691                             10900       
701                             21400       
711                             31700       
721                             41800       
731                             51700       
741                             61400       
751                             70900       
761                 4100            
771                 12200           
781                 20100           
791                 27800           
801                 35300           
811                 42600           
821                 49700           
831                 56600           
841                 63300           
851                 69800           
861                 76100           
871                 82200           
881     0               
891     4700                
901     9200                
911     13500               
921     17600               
931     21500               
941     25200               
951     28700               
961     32000               
971     35100               
981     38000               
991     40700               
1001    43200               
1011    45500               
1021    47600               
1031    49500               
1041    51200               
1051    52700               
1061    54000               
1071    55100               
1081    56000               
1091    56700               
1101    57200               
1111    57500               
1121    57600               
1131    57500               
1141    57200               
1151    56700               
1161    56000               
1171    55100               
1181    54000               
1191    52700               
1201    51200               
1211    49500               
1221    47600               
1231    45500               
1241    43200               
1251    40700               
1261    38000               
1271    35100               
1281    32000               
1291    28700               
1301    25200               
1311    21500               
1321    17600               
1331    13500               
1341    9200                
1351    4700                
1361    0               
1371                    
1381                128100          
1391                123800          
1401                119300          
1411                114600          
1421                109700          
1431                104600          
1441                99300           
1451                93800           
1461                88100           
1471                82200           
1481                76100           
1491                69800           
1501                63300           
1511                56600           
1521                49700           
1531                42600           
1541                35300           
1551                27800           
1561                20100           
1571                12200           
1581                4100            
1591                    
1601                            147400      
1611                            139700      
1621                            131800      
1631                            123700      
1641                            115400      
1651                            106900      
1661                            98200       
1671                            89300       
1681                            80200       
1691                            70900       
1701                            61400       
1711                            51700       
1721                            41800       
1731                            31700       
1741                            21400       
1751                            10900       
1761                            200     
1771                    
1781                                        156300  
1791                                        146000  
1801                                        135500  
1811                                        124800  
1821                                        113900  
1831                                        102800  
1841                                        91500   
1851                                        80000   
1861                                        68300   
1871                                        56400   
1881                                        44300   
1891                                        32000   
1901                                        19500   
1911                                        6800    
1921                    
1931                                                    173900
1941                                                    161600
1951                                                    149100
1961                                                    136400
1971                                                    123500
1981                                                    110400
1991                                                    97100
2001                                                    83600
2011                                                    69900
2021                                                    56000
2031                                                    41900
2041                                                    27600
2051                                                    13100
2061                    
2071                    
2081                    
2091                    
2101                    
2111                    
2121                    
2131                    
2141                    
2151                    
2161                    
2171                    
2181                    
2191                    
2201                    
2211                    
2221                    
2231                    
2241                    
2251                    
2261                    
2271                    
2281                    
2291                    
2301                    
2311                    
2321                    
2331                    
2341                    
2351                    
2361                    
2371                    
2381                    
2391                    
2401                    
2411                    
2421                    
2431                    
2441                    
2451                    
2461                    
2471                    
2481                    
2491                    
2501                    
2511                    
2521                    
2531                    
2541                    
2551                    
2561                    
2571                    
2581                    
2591                    
2601                    
2611                    
2621                    
2631                    
2641                    
2651                    
2661                    
2671                    
2681                    
2691                    
2701                    
2711                    
2721                    
2731                    
2741                    
2751                    
2761                    
2771                    
2781                    
2791                    
2801                    
2811                    
2821                    
2831                    
2841                    
2851                    
2861                    
2871                    
2881                    
2891                    
2901                    
2911                    
2921                    
2931                    
2941                    
2951                    
2961                    
2971                    
2981                    
2991
```

Also, here's the log of my program, that usess Gauss reduction to solve the equation

```
Gathered data: 
    Data[0]: 57200
    Axis[0]: 1101
    ---------------------------------
    Data[1]: 57500
    Axis[1]: 1111
    ---------------------------------
    Data[2]: 57600
    Axis[2]: 1121
    ---------------------------------
Equation 1: <3, 3333, 3703163, 172300>
Equation 2: <3333, 3703163, 4114658493, 191429300>
Equation 3: <3703163, 4114658493, 4572126198323, 212693876300>
------------- x on eq2 -------------
Equation 1: <9999, 11108889, 12342642279, 574275900>
Equation 2: <0, -600, -1333200, -12000>
Equation 3: <3703163, 4114658493, 4572126198323, 212693876300>
------------- x on eq3 -------------
Equation 1: <37027926837, 41138026715907, 45706816209828477, 2126637264671700>
Equation 2: <0, -600, -1333200, -12000>
Equation 3: <0, -4443555600, -9873647203200, -88804452000>
------------- y on eq1 -------------
Equation 1: <22216756102200, 0, -27421127491750126200, 782326038212136000>
Equation 2: <0, -24682816029544200, -54845217217647212400, -493656320590884000>
Equation 3: <0, -4443555600, -9873647203200, -88804452000>
------------- y on eq3 -------------
Equation 1: <22216756102200, 0, -27421127491750126200, 782326038212136000>
Equation 2: <0, -109679465391850895357520000, -243707772100692689484409440000, -2193589307837017907150400000>
Equation 3: <0, 0, 1645356516529416372000000, -1645356516529416372000000>
------------- z on eq1 -------------
Equation 1: <36554484428899446348435585218400000000, 0, 0, -43830325564112021049074552535855554400000000>
Equation 2: <0, -109679465391850895357520000, -243707772100692689484409440000, -2193589307837017907150400000>
Equation 3: <0, 0, 45117530809135000219824130943346146400000000, -45117530809135000219824130943346146400000000>
------------- z on eq2 -------------
Equation 1: <36554484428899446348435585218400000000, 0, 0, -43830325564112021049074552535855554400000000>
Equation 2: <0, -4948466658946288780765236702801378378302581056506142260928000000000000, 0, -11094462249357579446475660687680690324154386728686770949000576000000000000>
Equation 3: <0, 0, 10995492916178653670860355953624662756588335107556648103782016000000000000, -10995492916178653670860355953624662756588335107556648103782016000000000000>
a: -1
b: 2242
c: -1199041
dif: <-1, 2242, -1199041>
Associated equation: -1x^2 + 2242x + -1199041 = 0
```

So, if anyone can provide any help on how to correct my calculations, I would be appreciated.

If need any additional data, just ask for it.

**EDIT**
So, the problem was that the C program usses axis data "as is", and MS Excel uses a simple increment value.

I changed it to use `{111, 112, 113}` (as my f(x) values are placed on that correlative position) and it worked.

Comment: So are you only talking about "Serie1", here? Are the results from that?

Comment: Yes, that's It. Once I got "Serie 1" values, I have an equation to calculate subsequents regression curves (associated to "Serie 2", "Serie 3", and so on)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672385/excel-polynomial-curve-fitting-algorithm

Comment: Why 1101? The first series goes from x=881 to x=1361. With this series from 881 to 1361, and using Excel matrix functions to solve the linear system, I get the same equation as your C program. The quadratic fit computed by Excel (when adding it to the plot) has the same equation as well.

Comment: Are you comparing the two algorithms by feeding "precise" data , that fit on a parabola, or values with a "random" deviation from a parabola ?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: I use 1101 because it's the top of the parabola, and that is the first point that I can get with my C program.

Comment: @GCab I used an algorithm to construct the data table in a sequential mode, then after data analysis I created the C algorithm that skips some rows (e.g: it gets directly to x = 1101), so the data (x, f(x)) is the same on both scenarios

Comment: @BenedictW.J.Irwin unfortunately, the algorithm explained (https://www.efunda.com/math/leastsquares/lstsqr2dcurve.cfm) is the same I am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you and Excel are both right, but you don't compute the same thing.

- If you draw a XY plot in Excel and add a quadratic fit, you will get the same equation as found by your C program. It's the standard quadratic regression, and you can also find the coefficients within Excel using matrix formulas.
- If you draw a line plot, Excel will give you another equation. That's simply because then Excel does not know your X values, only the Y values, and it will simply pick X(i)=i.

Since your initial X series is regular with a step $10$, the second polynomial can be derived from the first by translating and scaling, and that's why you get a $-100=-10^2$ as leading coefficient.

Comment: Hi. I just found it (I was trying some variations on the meantime). The point here is that I was using {1101, 1121, 1131} as "y" values on regression, but Excel uses a linear increment value (on my case: {111, 112, 113}). Using this values gave me the same result but as you told, 100 times lower!